# Issue in getting user details and checking of roles in resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a app for which I use cookies to store the access token and get the user details by using API `getUser(accessToken)`. Consider a scenario where the user has logged in and I have access token in the cookies but don't have the user details. When the user tries to access a page, lets say /abc, how should I resolve the issue.
Here is what I am doing,
I have getUser(accessToken) API in run block. I also have events like `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', fuction(){});` in the run block.
when the user tries to access /abc, in resolve I check for the user role to confirm if the user have permission to access this page. Before I get the response of getUser() API my checking of user role takes place.
How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: And your code is...

Comment: Why dont you keep your user details in localStorage if you have valid accessToken in cookies?

Comment: Currently I was doing like that. But I want to know how can this done without saving in local storage.

Comment: OK, you can write a resolve function in $routeProvider which calls the api to get the details

Comment: Do you mean $routeProvider resolve in run block? Can you please share a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I think working with user roles would be the best option.
You could implement user roles as constant like this:

```
.constant('USER_ROLES', {
  all: '*',
  admin: 'admin',
  editor: 'editor',
  guest: 'guest'
})
```

A nice thing about constants is that they can be injected like services, which makes them easy to mock in your unit tests. It also allows you to easily rename them (change the values) later without having to change a bunch of files.

The logic related to authorization (access control) is best grouped in a service:

```
.factory('AuthService', function ($http, Session) {
  var authService = {};

  authService.login = function (credentials) {
    return $http
      .post('/login', credentials)
      .then(function (res) {
        Session.create(res.data.id, res.data.user.id,
                       res.data.user.role);
        return res.data.user;
      });
  };

  authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
    return !!Session.userId;
  };

  authService.isAuthorized = function (authorizedRoles) {
    if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
      authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
    }
    return (authService.isAuthenticated() &&
      authorizedRoles.indexOf(Session.userRole) !== -1);
  };

  return authService;
})
```

Most of the time you will want to disallow access to an entire page rather than hide a single element. Using a custom data object on the route (or state, when using UI Router), we can specify which roles should be allowed access. This example uses the UI Router style, but the same will work for ngRoute.

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, USER_ROLES) {
  $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard/index.html',
    data: {
      authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.admin, USER_ROLES.editor]
    }
  });
})
```

Next, we need to check this property every time the route changes (i.e. the user navigates to another page). This involves listening to the $routeChangeStart (for ngRoute) or $stateChangeStart (for UI Router) event:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    var authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles;
    if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
        // user is not allowed
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
      } else {
        // user is not logged in
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
      }
    }
  });
})
```

When a user is not authorized to access the page (because he’s not logged in or doesn’t have the right role), the transition to the next page will be prevented, so the user will stay on the current page.

Comment: This is perfect. But my requirement is different. After login() API I will get token, which is stored in session. Then I will get user role and details by calling getUser() API which is not stored locally. So when i refresh I don't have user details and roles. So every time I have to get this details which is called in run block. Then this code will not work. 

Can you help me how to do this?

Comment: Can't you just get the user details and store them in a session?

Comment: This our requirement. I can store only token. :(